# Does anyone have the procedure for using cartographer mapping 2d live?

Tags: python, mapping

i wanted to do mapping with catrographer_ros, however i find it difficult to do it as i am very new to ros. I tried to use the rosbag data i got from the lidar and launch it with backback_2d.launch. However, no mapping occured on the rviz.

The website https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ does not have the solution or steps to my problem

Comment: Please provide examples of what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the example i get from rplidar_s1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryET)

[THis is what it comes out when i use the cartographer_rosbag_validate -bag_filename your_bag.bag. I dont really understand it though. Then, i use the command 'roslaunch cartographer_ros demo_backpack_2d.launch bag_filename:=${HOME}/bagfiles/1.bag
' to launch the rviz with the rosbag. But no map is generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlTEP.png)

Comment: I am only using rplidar_s1 to get the data, not the turtlebot